# Netplan not changing active port when arp ip target is not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bonding, netplan

I am trying to configure Ubuntu server 20.0.4 with netplan and use dual copper lan port and optical convertors to achieve redundancy.

in my config I have bond created of two interfaces

```
bond-lan:
  interfaces:
    - enp3s0
    - enp4s0
  addresses: [192.168.221.28/27]
  gateway4: 192.168.221.1
  parameters:
    mode: active-backup
    primary: enp3s0
    arp-ip-targets: [192.168.221.1]
    arp-interval: 3000
    arp-validate: all
```

This configuration works if I unplug copper ethernet and loose link on either enp3s or enp4s. But when I loose link on optical cable (which doesn`t cause link loose on the device itself because the optical convertor keeps the link up) the device doesn't come back up.

From my understanding arp-ip-target, arp-interval and arp-validate should cause switch of primary interface to the other one and confirm functionality.

This isn't happening in my case.

Also if I leave the arp parameter the failover over copper still works.

If the there is requirement to have the physical interface down then I don't understand why there is an option to implement IP monitoring.

Am I understanding arp ip target wrong?

Comment: netplan creates a configuration for an other tool that will itself set the low level configuration on the interface(s). Can you see back this configuration using `ip -details link show dev bond-lan | grep arp_ip_target` (with `_` not `-` here)? If yes, does tcpdump on enp3s0 and enp4s0 capture such ARPs?